# ArrayBuffer ++= operation with Array for val type attribute

Tags: scala

This is the code block I have tried to understand += and ++=

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

scala> val a = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
a: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer()


scala> a += 1
res0: a.type = ArrayBuffer(1)

scala> a += (2,3,4);
res1: a.type = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala>  a ++= Array(5,6,7)
res4: a.type = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

what is **++=** operator in scala? How does it work? Why val is allowing merging of another array since val type should be constant and not against statically scoped feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adding elements to `ArrayBuffer`, you are using three different functions there.

`++=`, from doc

> def ++=(xs: TraversableOnce[A]): ArrayBuffer.this.type
>
> Appends a number of elements provided by a traversable object.

`+=`, from doc

> def +=(elem: A): ArrayBuffer.this.type
>
> Appends a single element to this buffer and returns the identity of the buffer.

and a overloaded `+=`, from doc

> def +=(elem1: A, elem2: A, elems: A*): ArrayBuffer.this.type
>
> adds two or more elements to this growable collection.

The `val a` is immutable and you are actually adding elements to mutable `ArrayBuffer`, without changing the reference to variable `a`.

**Edit**

```
scala> val a = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
a: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer()

scala> a += 1
res1: a.type = ArrayBuffer(1)

scala> a
res38: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1)

scala> a = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
<console>:33: error: reassignment to val
       a = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
         ^
```

As seen above when you are using `+=`, you are not changing the underlying reference to `val a`.

Comment: ArrayBuffer and Array are different types. So addition of them allowed for val type variable is my query. I heard that Scala is statically scoped langugage

Comment: ArrayBuffer is a buffer backed by an array. They are both mutable datastructures, so yes, you can add elements to them. On the other hand you cant reassign `val a` as its immutable.